# I keep on getting a KeyError in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I keep on getting a KeyError and not sure what I'm doing wrong here??

```
    import csv
    
    list_of_email_addresses = []
    with open("users.csv", newline="") as users_csv:
      user_reader = csv.DictReader(users_csv)
      for row in user_reader:
        list_of_email_addresses.append(row["Email"])
```

Comment: Apparently there's no `Email` column in the CSV file.

Comment: Add a sample of the CSV file to the question.

Comment: Better for your liking? Stack overflow did me the honor of commenting this out for me

Comment: I've seen lots of problems that people have posting code to SO, but never seen it automatically comment out the code.

Comment: Sorry, about the confusion. Still new to the SO/ python. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key error means the dictionary you are trying to access does not have the key you are using to get a value from it. It looks like you are trying to access the row dictionaries "Email" key. Your csv file does not have an "Email" column in some rows and thus is giving you this error. To solve, you can do row.get("Email","") which will just return an empty string if there is no email.

You can also just do a check before you append so that you arent adding empy items to your list by doing

```
  for row in user_reader:
    email = row.get("Email")
    if email is None: continue
    list_of_email_addresses.append(email)
```

Comment: If there's no Email columnm, the whole code is pointless. He should use the correct column name, not hide the error.

Comment: @Barmar Thats assuming every row has an email column, which I dont know if it may or may not, so I chose to provide the above solution rather than the one you propose.

Comment: In a CSV file, all rows have the same columns, since the column names are defined in the header line.

Answer (score 2):

In python, you access a dictionary like this.

```py
myDict = {1: "foo", 2: "bar"}
print(myDict[1], myDict[2])
>>> foo, bar
```

I imagine your CSV file doesn't have the column you're trying to access as a key and that's why a KeyError is being raised.